# Convert StringTimestamp datastage to Timestamp db2

Tags: db2, datastage

i am working on ETL job in datastage  , a simple one Source ---> tRANsformer -----> destination
the source is a csv file , the destination is db2 base , so the prob is that the csv file contains a string timestamp  like this
[image]

and i need to put it the db2 stage this is my table that i created with a script
[image]

this is the transformer config
[image]
[image]

and this is my prob this error appears
[image]
that means this in english
update_or_insert, 3: Unhandled conversion error in the "SEC_DAT_DATE_INSERT" zone from the source
type "timestamp" to the target type "timestamp [microseconds]":
source value = "*****************". The result does not accept a NULL value and there is no
handle_null to specify a default value

I don't know what it means that's the prob if anyone could help that would be nice thanks

Comment: Which part of this message: "he result does not accept a NULL value and there is no handle_null to specify a default value" do you find unclear?

Answer (score 0):

First off, verify how Excel has handled the timestamp. Change the display format so that it conforms to ISO 8601, namely YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS format, before you export it to CSV. Check the CSV file using a text editor (Notepad or Wordpad) to confirm that the timestamp format is correct.
Then change the StringToTimestamp() function so that it reflects the new format (or leave out the format entirely if this is your default format.
Note that the Else part of your expression uses a string. Perhaps you need to wrap that in a StringToTimestamp() function.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to check weather you have marked that column as *key* in the source (can happen by mistake) if so then deselect the key check box and see weather *nullable* is set to **YES** for that column in source ,if not then try and run on nullable column with **YES** selected. hope this helps.